# VSE: How to set a custom Proxy percentage size; for example 10%

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there an option to set custom % on Proxy sizes?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only choose between 25, 50, 75 and 100%.

It's hard coded as you can see when you try to autocomplete the following in a python console:

```
>>> bpy.ops.sequencer.enable_proxies(
enable_proxies()
bpy.ops.sequencer.enable_proxies(proxy_25=False, proxy_50=False, proxy_75=False, proxy_100=False, override=False)
```

Comment: However, you might be able to use external tools (but with one of the four available sizes) and use a custom proxy directory building them with 10% on your own... But that might be a different and more difficult question ;-)

Comment: Thanks Samoth. I've found these too. But somehow they are not setting any percentage. I'm looking for the source file to change it like you suggested. Setting the Custom Output to use a Custom % (User Input Field) would be great.